# npm request not getting json response when doing body.{object}

Tags: json, node.js, request

So I am making request to twitch to get some streamer data using npm response.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/streams/:user', function(req, res, next) {

    request('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + req.params.user, function ( error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
        {
            res.send(body);
        } 
        else 
        {
            res.send(404);
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I do res.send(body) it gives me back my json object printed to screen nicely.

```
{"_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/allencoded","channel":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/allencoded"},"stream":null}
```

So I want to not get all that back but instead just get the self url.
I then thought I would do something like:

```
res.send(body._links.self)
```

That returned nothing but a blank screen.

How do print out just the self url?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`body` is a string. You have to parse it as JSON first:

```
res.json(JSON.parse(body)._links.self);
```

Comment: I literall just figured this out by doing 
   var obj = JSON.parse(body);
   res.send(obj._links);

Comment: is not possible to request for JSON instead of converting? Lie the answer below which I guess it should work with the better performance

Answer (score 13):

This question is little old, yet, the following also seems more helpful. In request, you can pass `json: true` and request library returns you the json object.

replace following line,

> ```
> request('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + req.params.user, function ( error, response, body) {
> ```

with the one below

> ```
> request({'url':`https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/${req.params.user}`, 'json': true }, function ( error, response, body) {
> ```

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks